Polynomial divisibility along hyperplanes
Let $\mathbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the algebra of polynomials in $n$ real variables. A matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{(n+1)\times n}$ can be used to pull-back polynomials
$$
A^*\colon \mathbb R[x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}] \to \mathbb R[x_1,\dots,x_{n}],\quad A^*p(x_1,\dots, x_n)= p\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}x_j ,\dots, \sum_{j=1}^n a_{(n+1),j}x_j\right), 
$$ and defines a relation as follows:
$$
p|_Aq \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad (A^*p)|(A^*q) \text{ in } \mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_n],\qquad p,q\in \mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}] 
$$
That is, $p|_Aq$ iff you can divide their pull-backs by $A$.  If $A$ has full rank we can view $A^*p$ as the restriction to the hyperplane $\mathrm{rg}(A)$ (together with a change of coordinates, which does not affect divisibility).
Question 1: Suppose $p|_A q$ for sufficiently many $A$'s, do we already have $p|q$ in $\mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}]$?
In general the answer is no, as we see e.g. with $p(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2^2$ and $q(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$. These are homogeneous of degrees $3$ and $2$ respectively, homogeneity is preserved by pull-back and homogeneous polynomials in one variable are always divisible (if the enumerator has a larger degree).
However, for $n\ge 2$ divisibility of the pull-backs does not come for free, so there is hope. I'd be happy to know what happens for homogeneous polynomials of adjacent degrees. So let's write $\mathbb R_d[x_1,\dots, x_{n}]$ for the $d$-homogeneous polynomials.
Question 2: Let $n\ge 2$ and $d\ge 1$ and $(p,q)\in\mathbb R_{d+1}[x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}]\times \mathbb R_d[x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}]$ with $p|_A q$ for all matrices $A$ of full rank. Do we necessarily have $p|q$?
Already for $n=2$ and $d=1$ I am not sure.
There is a more geometric viewpoint: Assume $(n,d)=(2,1)$ and view $(p,q)$ as a point in $X=\mathbb R P^{5}\times \mathbb R P^2$. Then the divisibility relation cuts out a variety $\mathcal V_A\subset X$. So we have to understand $\bigcap_A \mathcal V_A\subset X$.

Maybe you know this, but replacing $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$, and assuming $p$ is irreducible, this has a positive answer, I think. $p$ and $q$ define hypersurfaces $X,Y \subset \mathbb C^{n+1}$, and intersecting with any subvectorspace $H \subset \mathbb C^{n+1}$, you have $X \cap H \subset Y$. But if $H$ is arbitrary, this implies $X \subset Y$, so that by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $p | q$.

Thanks! So do I understand correctly? We need $\mathbb C$ to apply the Nullstellensatz, which gives $q|p^r$ for some $r\in \mathbb N$ (sorry, I switched roles of $p$ and $q$) and if $p$ is irreducible this implies $q|p$. And in my $n=1$ counterexample the polynomial $p$ is reducible. // This clears up a lot, but unfortunately doesn't quite cover the situation I had in mind, so I'll leave the question open for now.
